# Efficiently Calculate Minimum Distance Between 2 Sets of Points in 3D?

Tags: algorithm

I have two sets of 3D coordinates, A and B.

I would like to compute the **minimum distance from a point in A to a point in B** as efficiently as possible.

I am aware of divide-and-conquer algorithms in *O(n · log[n])* when the points lie on a plane (See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/).

However, I'd like to know the most efficient known solution for coordinates in 3D.

Comment: In the question you are talking about "2 sets of points" but in the description you just mention "a point A and point B" (so 2 points, which distance is trivial to calculate). Not sure to understand what you want.

Comment: @tigrou I don't think you've understood. I stated that A and B are both sets. We would like to find the minimum value in the set {distance(x, y) | x in A, y in B}.

Comment: Linked problem is not quite reliable for this task because you need distance between point from distinct sets. 2D case [on-topic article from 1983](http://www-cgrl.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/publications/mindist.pdf), you can look for its citation in later sources to know about progress in 3D . Perhaps your sets are special  - for example, separated - in this case problem becomes easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have two sets of 3D coordinates, A and B.
>
> I would like to compute the minimum distance from a point in A to a
> point in B as efficiently as possible.

Since you are aware of the divide-and-conquer approach for 2D coordinates, you can simply extrapolate that to 3D, it's not much of a difference.

Here's an implementation [**Playground link**](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/online-cpp14-compiler/be8ffffe-0632-49e8-b89e-88e9efb0a943):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<double> vd;

vd operator-(const vd& a, const vd& b) {
  vd c(3);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] - b[i];
  return c;
}

double dist(const vd& a, const vd& b) {
  double dx = a[0] - b[0];
  double dy = a[1] - b[1];
  double dz = a[2] - b[2];
  return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
}

double min_distance(const vector<vd>& A, const vector<vd>& B) {
  vector<vd> C = A;
  C.insert(C.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
  sort(C.begin(), C.end());
  int n = C.size();
  double ans = 1e18;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n && C[j][0] - C[i][0] < ans; j++) 
      ans = min(ans, dist(C[i], C[j]));
      
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  vector<vd> A {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
  vector<vd> B {{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}};

  double min_dist = min_distance(A, B);

  cout << "Minimum distance between sets A and B: " << min_dist << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The time complexity of this solution is also O(N log N), courtesy of the `sort` function.